# Problem with wput and vsftpd

Tags: 16.04, server, ftp, vsftpd, wireshark

I am trying to upload/modify files in my ftp server in Ubuntu 16.04 (in **/srv/ftp** directory) using **wput** from a remote host.

I get the error **553 Could not create file** in Wireshark.

Here is my **/etc/vsftpd.conf** :

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
ftpd_banner=Ftp Server
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you enabled the `write_enable=YES` the issue seems to be folder permission issue.

You'll need to make sure that the user which logged in to the ftp-server, has the needed read/write/execute permissions to the folder he tries to write.

You might need to execute something like: (replace the ftp-user-name and /ftp-folder with real data)

1. Change the owner of the folder, to the user logged-in via ftp

   `sudo chown user-name /ftp-folder-full-path`
2. Change folder write permission, to be write-able by its owner

   `sudo chmod 755 /ftp-folder-full-path`